# IBM Worklight - JSONStore support

Tags: blackberry, ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

Does Worklight's JSONStore feature supports BlackBerry?

I mean, can I use it while developing applications for BlackBerry?

Comment: To add to Idan's answer below, there's a JavaScript-only version of JSONStore that can be used everywhere (to the best of my knowledge). However, you don't get production features like security and it uses LocalStorage to save data instead of a more persistent file in the native layer. It's only meant for production for Android and iOS devices and simulators.

Comment: Did you try adapters? I think you can do JSONStore on Blackberry with Adapters.

Answer (score 2):

The [JSONStore feature](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/c_jsonstore_overview.html) is only available on iOS and Android devices and simulators.

Comment: Starting with version 6.2, there are other platforms that support JSONStore. 

From the [6.3 documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_jsonstore_api_concepts.html?lang=en), _JSONStore provides API reference information for hybrid Android, iOS, Windows 8, and Windows Phone 8, and native Android and iOS applications_